# What's the Regular Expression that matches culture names?

Tags: regex

I'd like to use a regular expression to filter culture names (like en-US or pt-BR). Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$
```

Or more general (see [RFC 4647](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647)):

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,8}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})*$
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately my ASP.NET MVC2 route doesn't work anyway :/

Comment: @Rodrigo Waltenberg: Note that `^` and `$` mark the begin and end of the string respectively. Maybe you need that regular expression without these anchors.

Comment: What would have to be done so this can work with bash? with grep more specifically

Answer (score 1):

If you want follow the [RFC 4646](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-4646.txt) format for the culture name (who is `<languagecode2>-<country/regioncode2>`, where `<languagecode2>` is the language code and `<country/regioncode2>` is the subculture code)

**Example**: "en", "en-UK", "fr", "fr-FR", ...

Use this Regex:

```
^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})*
```

C# code sample

```
Regex.IsMatch(culture, @"^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})*$")
```

Comment: this won't match `zh-Hans`.... https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this to match all available Culture:

```
^(\w{2,3}-\w{2,4}(-\w{2})?)$
```

samples:

de-DE

bm-Latn-ML

brx-IN

vai-Vaii-LR

Answer (score 0):

@Gumbo is right. A test:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: reg = re.compile("^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$")

In [3]: url = 'en-US'

In [4]: m = reg.match(url)
```

the result shows that it Matched.

Comment: Please refrain from posting non answers like this. If you have an answer, post it. If you are commenting on an answer, post a comment on that answer.

Comment: Humble apologies. I will take care in future. Thanks. :)